# Nested array for org.json

Tags: java, arrays, json

I tried to build the nested array for the following json blob using jsonobject and jsonarray. For some reason, the object is failing. Any thoughts - please, how best we can put this format.

```
{
  "reporter_desc": "pot",
  "timestamp": "1487830751",
  "incidents": [
    {
      "src_ip": 822382162,
      "exploit": "scan",
      "incident_type": 3,
      "occurred": "1487830751",
      "description": "pot scan"
    }
```

Here is the JSONObject and JSONArray :

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("reporter_desc", "mtpot");
object.put("timestamp", "1487830751");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

JSONObject arrayElement = new JSONObject();
arrayElement.put("src_ip", 822382162);
arrayElement.put("exploit", "scan");
arrayElement.put("incident_type", 3);
arrayElement.put("occurred", "1487830751");
arrayElement.put("description", "pot vulnerability scan");
array.put("incidents");
object.put("incidents", array);
```

Comment: Looks like you don't want the `array.put("incidents");`

Comment: I tried it and it still failing.

Comment: Then what if you add your arrayelements directly in the new array you've created like `array.put("src_ip", 822382162);` etc. instead of `arrayElement.put("src_ip", 822382162);`? Drop the `array.put("incidents");` and just finish up adding the array to object with `object.put("incidents", array);`

Comment: Maybe I miss something but where you assign the arrayElement into array?

Comment: @Theo - sorry for the delay. I have done exactly using array.put and finished with object.put. It was throwing the following error :
"The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type HashMap. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be parameterized."

Comment: The modified one is as below :

JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("reporter_desc", "pot");
object.put("timestamp", "1487830751");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

array.put("src_ip", 822382162);
array.put("exploit", "scan");
array.put("incident_type", 3);
array.put("occurred", "1487830751");
array.put("description", "pot vulnerability scan");
object.put("incidents", array);